# Why I can't use the std::map[ ] to add a string, but std::map.at() works?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap

My problem is why the s += t.getM()[0]; in the example code raise

```
main.cpp:44:20: error: passing ‘const std::map >’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I checked the cppreference and it says both return a reference.

In addition, why both operator[] and .at() work for std::vector?

Example code is here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class test {
    public:
        test(string str) {
            vec.push_back(str);
            mp[0] = str;
            
        }   
        
        const vector<string>& getV() const {
            return vec;
        }
        
        const map<int, string>& getM() const {
            return mp;
        }
        
    private:
        vector<string> vec;
        map<int, string> mp;
};

int main()
{
    string s;
    test t("hello ");
    s += t.getV().at(0);
    s += t.getV()[0];
    s += t.getM().at(0);
    s += t.getM()[0];
    cout << s;
}
```

Comment: map::operator[] only applies to mutable (non-const) maps. Indeed, it inserts an element if there isn't already one, while `at` doesn't. That's a big misfeature in my opinion, but it's been like that since the beginning. You can remove the `s+=` part of the lines and still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map::operator[]` only works for a non-`const` `std::map`. [The documentation on `std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) explains this pretty well. Here's an excerpt from the beginning of the page:

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.

As you can see, if the key doesn't exist, it inserts a new key/value pair into the map. Obviously, this wouldn't work for `const` maps because you can't insert elements into them since they're immutable. Why there isn't a `const` overload for the operator that will not create a new value, I don't know. But that's just how it is.

`std::map::at()`, however doesn't work exactly like `std::map::operator[]`. Again, an excerpt from the [documentation of `std::map::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at):

> Returns a reference to the mapped value of the element with key equivalent to key. If no such element exists, an exception of type `std::out_of_range` is thrown.

Furthermore, the function has a `const` overload too: `const T& at(const Key& key) const;` So it can work for `const` maps.

---

> In addition, why both operator[] and .at() work for std::vector?

Because [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) and [`std::vector::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) work very similarly, except `std::vector::at()` does bounds checking while `std::vector::operator[]` doesn't. Neither will create a new value (because that's just not how vectors work) and both have `const` overloads. In fact, the documentation for `std::vector::operator[]` even addresses the difference between it and `std::map::operator[]`:

> Unlike `std::map::operator[]`, this operator never inserts a new element into the container. Accessing a nonexistent element through this operator is undefined behavior.

(It's undefined behavior because, as I previously mentioned, `operator[]` does no bounds checking.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [@mediocrevegetable1's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67135719/14078020), the following increases the size of the container:

```
class test {
    public:
           ...
           map<int, string>& getM() {
               return mp;
           }
    private:
           ...
}

int main()
{
    string s;
    test t("hello ");
    s += t.getV().at(0);
    s += t.getV()[0];
    s += t.getM().at(0);
    s += t.getM()[0];
    cout << s;
    cout << t.getM().size() << endl;  // prints 1
    auto temp = t.getM()[1]; // Key=1 does not exist in the container and hence is added
    cout << t.getM().size() << endl; // prints 2
}
```

Also, I got better hint regarding the issue from clang instead of gcc:

```
no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const map<int, std::string>' (aka 'const map<int, basic_string<char> >')
```